# Mendelson logic exercise 2.31.e solution attempt.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

This question is from "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , page 78.I have to prove this following theorem

> $\vdash (\forall x)(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x)) \to (\forall x) \lnot A(x,x)$

**My attempt:**

1. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x))$  [hyp]
2. $(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x))$             [Axiom A4]
3. $A(x,x) \to \lnot A(x,x))$                         [Axiom A4]
4. $A(x,x)$                                           [Hyp]
5. $\lnot A(x,x)$ [from 3 & 4 by MP]
6. $A(x,x) \land \lnot A(x,x)$ [Conjunction Introduction]
7. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x)) , A(x,x) \vdash A(x,x) \land \lnot A(x,x)$
8. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x)) \vdash  \lnot A(x,x)$ [contraduction theorem]
9. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x)) \vdash (\forall x)\lnot  A(x,x)$ [Gen]
10. $\vdash (\forall x)(\forall y)(A(x,y) \to \lnot A(y,x)) \to  (\forall x)\lnot  A(x,x)$ [Deduction theorem]

I am not sure if my attempt is correct or not.Can someone verify it for me?

Comment: Expressions 2->6 lacking quantifiers don't make much sense.

Comment: @Maxence1402 I derived 6 from 5 and 4 using the "conjunction introduction" [$B,C \vdash B \land C$]

Comment: Basically, the proof is correct; the only issue is: what are the rules of Mendelson's system?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA MP and Gen.

Comment: Yes, but... are the "derived rules" of Conj Intro and similar already added to the system? If so, you can use them; if not, you have to prove them.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know They are not added to the system.But they are given as lemmas to prove at exercise 2.30. I know how to prove them within the system .

Comment: Perfect........